# How to run a java file from different directory to include all of the output from where i need to build the Dockerfile?

Tags: java, dockerfile, javac, javacompiler

I have a java file inside `JavaFile` directory from the below screenshot and want to run that java file from other directory (i.e) from

> C:\Priyanka\Docker-AppCodes\java-docker-app

[image: Folder path]

My java file is present inside the JavaFile Folder. How should I run the `java` file. I am using the  command

```
RUN javac JavaFile/Hello.java
```

to run in DockerFile. My `Java` File `Hello.java` contains the below code.

```
class Hello{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        System.out.println("This is java app \n by using Docker");  
    }  
}
```

But I am receiving the File not Found Error. Please help me to resolve this.

The Docker file contains the below code:

```
FROM java:8  
COPY . /var/www/java  
WORKDIR /var/www/java  
RUN javac JavaFile/Hello.java  
CMD ["java", "Hello"]
```

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the Dockerfile? The javaFile needs to be copied inside the docker image before being used.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include all of the output from when you try to build the Dockerfile?

Comment: are you running docker build command from the directory where the Dockerfile is present? Just a check

Comment: yes @RohithV I am running from the Dockerfile Directory

Comment: can anyone please help me resolve this